# Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import

Tags: reactjs, deployment, hosting, bundle, vite

**Background**

I have a react app with Vite that I'm occasionally changing the images that are being displayed.
The app is hosted to Render, so that every time I push to the main branch of the repository, there is an auto deploy.

**The Problem**

The last deployment has failed, with this message in the logs:

```
Aug 15 01:07:07 PM  > tsc && vite build
Aug 15 01:07:07 PM  
Aug 15 01:07:10 PM  vite v4.2.1 building for production...
Aug 15 01:07:10 PM  transforming...
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  ✓ 28 modules transformed.
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  ✓ built in 1.13s
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/assets/projects/privateGarden.jpg" from "/opt/render/project/src/src/components/Projects.tsx".
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  `build.rollupOptions.external`
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  error during build:
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/assets/projects/privateGarden.jpg" from "/opt/render/project/src/src/components/Projects.tsx".
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  `build.rollupOptions.external`
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM      at onRollupWarning (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:46368:19)
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM      at onwarn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:46138:13)
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM      at Object.onwarn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25171:13)
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM      at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23806:26)
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM      at file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23766:26
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! errno 1
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! portfolio-ido-band@0.0.0 build: `tsc && vite build`
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR!
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio-ido-band@0.0.0 build script.
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-08-15T10_07_11_518Z-debug.log
Aug 15 01:07:11 PM  ==> Build failed
```

**What I tried**

Because all I did was simply change the image file, all I had to do next is to update the route of the import to match the name of new image file, because the variable name stays the same - that's it.

The project works perfectly well locally, and when running `npm run build`, the build process ends without any error, but when trying to open `index.html` file in `dist` - the result in a blank page.

In the last commit in Github you can even see the new image file presented as an image, with 'Added' title.

**The Code**

The image files is located in the `public` directory inside the root directory of the project.
This is how I import the image:

```
import pgImg from '/assets/projects/privateGarden.jpg'
```

and then i just use the it like so: `<img src={pgImg} />`